# Asymptotic Expansion around minus infinity

Tags: series-expansion

Consider

```
 f[x_, a_] := Simplify[Sqrt[a*x + x^2], Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

Then if I run:

```
 Series[f[x, 0], {x, Infinity, 1}]

 Series[f[x, 1], {x, Infinity, 1}]
```

The first results in Abs[x] as expected but the leading term of the second Series is x.
How do I force it to be Abs[x]? 
The background is that this is a simplified version of a more complicated function and I am interested in the asymptotic behavior at both +Infinity and -Infinity.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange, you can format code with the `{}` button, or starting a new paragraph with four spaces.

Comment: It is not clear, why are you thinking about the absolute value? You have in mind a real x and expand it in the vicinity of the infinity. It is positive. The result of your first expression `Series[f1[x, 0], {x, Infinity, 1}]` was for me (MMa11, Win7) as follows: `SeriesData[x, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {1}, -1, 2, 1]`, Not `Abs[x]`.

Comment: I would also like to know the asymptotic behavior at -Infinity. Running

Comment: The expansion at -infinity does show a long-standing problem with `Series`. About all I can say is I am hoping to see it improved in the not-too-distant future, possibly version 11.1. (As a matter of general policy we do not make comments like that. I'm making an exception mostly as a way to hold myself to it.)

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!